# Jmeter Regex trim space

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to take CSRF value with regex extractor.

[image]

Then use that variable to my post parameter.

[image]

But there is space in csrf parameter.

[image]

How to get rid that space? Thanks for your help

This is source csrf which i take csrf

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Double check the place where you're assigning the variable, the regular expression extractor per se won't add any whitespaces anywhere, you can check the extracted variable value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script).
2. [Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), I would suggest going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) instead, the relevant configuration would be as simple as:

   [image]

More information: [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 3):

I don't get the requirement of `?` in the regex where it captures each character individually as a full match and in capturing group 1. Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/DZCgRw/1). But you can add that if it's required for this particular usecase with jmeter.

`.+` captures any character including space characters.

You can either do `(\S+)` to capture all non space characters as you don't have space characters in the middle or `(\w+)` to capture all word characters as you only have letters and numbers in your string.

**EDIT**

Sorry I got your question wrong the first time. Here is a regex that captures the value field of `csrfmiddlewaretoken` on first capturing group.

```
name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"\svalue="\s?(\w+)"
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1c4u3M/1)

This should omit any leading space characters in the secret. If this didn't work, I suspect that you have an additional space added where you assign this extracted values to the variable.

Comment: Great. Let me know if that didn't go well. You can also play round and learn regex with https://regex101.com/

Comment: Did you try with `?` in the group as well?

Comment: I updated my answer. It wourld be great if you can add plain text than images specially with a question on a regex so that people can copy and use the input/output samples to try things out. Hope my edit solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
\s*([1-9]+.*?)
```

Try this and see.

**Update**

Try this: This must work.

```
name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"\svalue="([^”]+?)"
```